# animateValueAsState tween crash (AnimationVector cannot contain a NaN)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

Not able to reproduce locally, seeing multiple crashes on firebase. It seems to affect different users consistently across various devices and Android versions.

The stack trace does not give any indication that it's an issue with our component, except a duration of an animation, I've tried to do some digging but cannot reproduce.

Below is a similarly coded section of code on the components where we found this anaimationDuration value from crash:

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable(
   someData: SomeData,
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = modifier,
        visible = ...
    ) {

        val progressValue = remember(someData) {
            (someData.value1.toFloat() / someData.value2.toFloat()) * 100
        }

        val someDataAnimation by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = progressValue,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 700 <- duration value from a stacktrace
            )
        )

        val angle = remember(someDataAnimation) {
            someDataAnimation * 360 / 100
        }

        Box(...) {
            Canvas(...) {
                drawArc(
                   ...,
                   sweepAngle = angle,
                   ...
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnimationVector cannot contain a NaN. AnimationVector1D: value = NaN. Animation: TargetBasedAnimation: NaN -> 41.12,initial velocity: AnimationVector1D: value = 0.0, duration: 700 ms,animationSpec: androidx.compose.animation.core.VectorizedTweenSpec@3d4a9b6, playTimeNanos: 0
    androidx.compose.animation.core.TargetBasedAnimation.getValueFromNanos(Animation.kt:242)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.SuspendAnimationKt.animate(SuspendAnimation.kt:233)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable$runAnimation$2.invokeSuspend(Animatable.kt:305)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable$runAnimation$2.invoke(:8)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable$runAnimation$2.invoke(:2)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex$mutate$2.invokeSuspend(InternalMutatorMutex.kt:119)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex$mutate$2.invoke(:8)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex$mutate$2.invoke(:4)
    kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
    kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:264)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex.mutate(InternalMutatorMutex.kt:112)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex.mutate$default(InternalMutatorMutex.kt:109)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable.runAnimation(Animatable.kt:295)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable.animateTo(Animatable.kt:238)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable.animateTo$default(Animatable.kt:225)
    androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimateAsStateKt$animateValueAsState$3$1.invokeSuspend(AnimateAsState.kt:426)
    kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
    androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
    androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

**Versions:**

```
Jetpack Compose version: compiler 1.4.0, compose-bom:2023.01.00
Android Studio Build: any
Kotlin version: 1.8.0
```

Additionally, I openned [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/272576533) in Google Issue Tracker

I tried to do some research, but all I found was that the NaN value is the result of dividing a Floating/Double zero by a Floating/Double zero.

Of course, I tried setting the progressValue to NaN or Zero, but it didn't have any effect

Also this crash somehow relates to the following [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232030217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

In any Compose animation progress value, make sure that this value cannot be NaN at runtime. For some reason, if you pass NaN directly to the targetValue of your composable, the crash is not triggered, but after manual check of divider value in `progressValue` the crashes disappeared over time from the crashlytics:

```kotlin
val progressValue = remember(someData) {
    val divisor = someData.value2.toFloat()
    ((someData.value1.toFloat() / divisor) * 100).takeIf { divisor != 0f } ?: 0f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `progressValue` turns into a `NaN` (as indicated by the stacktrace). This usually happens when we e.g. perform a division by 0.

One solution would be to wrap your `someData.valueX.toFloat()` with a `max(1, someData.value1.toFloat())` call so that you will never divide by 0.